# How can I reference a JavaScript object if I have the name in a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have several objects on a page... I know the name of one of the objects and it's stored in a variable called `editorId`. How can I access that object's methods? `editorId.someFunction()` doesn't work because the value of the variable is the object's name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a global variable you could just do `var editor = window[editorID];`.

If it's local you could do `var editor = (new Function('return ' + editorID))();`.

Then you could do `editor.blah()`;

Comment: This is the best solution, using `window[editorID].someFunction();` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to an HTML element on the page, you can use:

```
document.getElementById(editorId);
```

If you are referring to the name of a JavaScript object, you can try `eval()`, which is not very efficient:

```
var obj = eval(editorId);
// obj.someFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

use `document.getElementsByName(editorId)`. Alternatively if your name is actually an ID, use `getElementById()`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp